# Choosing inrush current limiting resistor for a mains rectifier

Tags: resistors, mains, rectifier, inrush-current

I am having a trouble with a mains rectifier. Simplified schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzcCBS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Only problem I have is that R1 sometime explodes during circuit power-up.
It happens when C1 is discharged, and there is a 310v peak in input.

Due to resistive nature of capacitor charge, same amount of energy as stored in capacitor (~50mJ) should be dissipated *somwhere else*

The simple solution is to whack a giant 2W resistor, capable of withstanding high energy pulses, but I am having a limited space. Also, if I remove a resistor, then fuse will blow up

I would like to use a few 0805 in a row, but they explode sometimes.

I assume that this is due to the fact that metal film is extremely thin and not capable of holding a significant amount of energy. Carbon film should be better.

How this problem is solved in modern PSU? Is there some special resistors available?

Comment: Metal film resistor only has a VERY THIN resistive element. Use a bulk carbon-composition resistor.

Comment: The "special resistors" you mention are called inrush current limiters, or ICLs. They're made of a material that lowers in resistivity when it heats up, so that its resistance falls after it limits the inrush current. They're also designed to be able to actually handle the inrush current, too.

Answer (score 2):

Typical solution to limit inrush current is to use NTC thermistors instead of plain resistors, See this [TDK publication for example](https://product.tdk.com/info/en/products/protection/current/ntc-limiter/technote/apn-ntc-limiter.html).

[image]

Here is [an application note](https://www.ametherm.com/blog/inrush-current/transformer-inrush-current-40va-transformer) on how to properly select an NTC resistor for an application.

Comment: Are NTC some big volumetric-type resistor, with all that volume to absorb the transient heat?

Comment: Anatherm have some very small NTC surge suppressors: https://www.ametherm.com/datasheets/sl0322101   These are only 3mm, but they will (as all NTC surge suppressors) run hot at their rated current. In this application there probably isn't enough heat generated to get them down much less than 50 Ohms or so, but that may well be suitable for the OP.

Comment: @JackCreasey, there is a whole spectrum of such devices, for every power and current rating and initial resistance at 25 deg.C